# Rewrite URL with multiple parameters

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, clean-urls

I have a URL that sometimes has one or more parameters and I want to be able to rewrite accordingly.

The URLs are as follows:

```
/index.php?pagetitle=Home
```

I have managed to get this URL to display how I want using the following:

```
/Home
```

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+) index.php?pagetitle=$1 [NC,L]
```

I would also like to be able to have the same URL, but with article ID

```
.com/index.php?pagetitle=Home&articleid=20
```

which i would like to display like this:

```
.com/Home/20
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to get it to work on more than one parameter.

UPDATE: 
Ok so i managed to get the below to work using :
    index.php?pagetitle=$1&articleid=$2

Which displays as:
    .com/Home/20

I have tried to take it a step further and be able to use the article title as well the rule i tried is as follows.

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(?:/([0-9a-zA-Z]+))(?:/([0-9]*))?/?$ index.php?pagetitle=$1&articletitle=$2&articleid=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

So would display as :
    .com/Home/ArticleTitle/20

But it doesnt want to work for me does any one know what i am doing wrong and thanks again in advance.

http://karpium.co.uk/Home/Baits/20 - This Url Works

http://karpium.co.uk/Home - But this url doesnt work where as it does when just using the pagetitle= and articleid=

Comment: I used to bang my head around this pretty url Apache routing but I then realised it's easier done in PHP. Try SLIM PHP„ it has easy restful routing and very high perfomance and more feature reach than Apache .conf files

Comment: Thank you main reason for trying to do it in htaccess is because its a college project and we have to create the website in as little scripting as possible but i will have a look for future projects thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following Rule :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(?:/([0-9]*))?/?$ index.php?pagetitle=$1&articleid=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Could you add some explanation to this answer?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so seems like i have fixed it using 3 different rewrite rules which are as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?pagetitle=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(?:/([0-9a-zA-Z]+))?/?$ index.php?pagetitle=$1&articletitle=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)(?:/([0-9a-zA-Z]+))(?:/([0-9]*))?/?$ index.php?pagetitle=$1&articletitle=$2&articleid=$3 [NC,L,QSA]
```

If any one can shed some light onto a few parts of the regex for me it would be very much appreciated:

What do the following mean?

?:/

?/?

Thanks again for all the help :)

Comment: **?:** is used to for non-capturing groups . **(?:/(foo))** captures **foo** and saves the captured valued as **$1** , without **?:** the capture group **(/(foo))** captures **/foo** . and **/?** means the **/** is optional. You should read about regex. there are alot of sites and tutorials availabe. Search google.